# Turn excel list into signs

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, layout

I have a list in excel  with a title and varying multiple lines of text. What could I use to create a template for each "section" of my list and have it be populated automatically? As it is now I manually take all the elements and paste them in a powerpoint page.

Example data of table in Excel:

```
Code, Name, Type
1111, Apple, Fruit
1313, Orange, Fruit
2222, Chicken, Animal
2333, Dog, Animal
```

I want to make 2 printable pages:

```
nr 1
A big title saying "Fruit"
One line for each line with type "Fruit"

nr 2
A big title saying "Animal"
One line for each line with type "Animal"
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you are looking for a software recommendation that is off-topic for [Super User](https://superuser.com/) but  you could try the Stack Exchange site [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  If you are using Office Software then you will want to google mail-merge.

Comment: One line for each line with type "Animal"/"Fruit", do these lines includ the Code number?

Comment: Hire a graphic designer?

Comment: In Power Point, try Insert>Table>Excel spreadsheet. You can then paste in there and format the table how you want it to appear

Answer (score 0):

Make a list on a new sheet, like on the picture below and with formulas like these:

```
G2  =IF(MOD(COLUMNS($F$1:F1);4)=1;INT((COLUMNS(F$1:$G1)+4)/4);"")
G3  =IFERROR(INDEX(UNIQUE($C$2:$C$27);F2);"")
G4  =FILTER($A$2:$C$31;$C$2:$C$31=F3;"")
```

Hide helperrow

[image]

Adjust print settings
[image]

Print as Pdf

Or try to use in Word Mail Merge